# How to only get the strings that in english (the ones from res/values) using aapt?

Tags: android, apk, aapt

I am trying to extract the English strings from an APK file using the aapt command in Linux. However, when I run the command `aapt dump --values strings app.apk`, it displays all the strings from all languages in the APK.

Comment: May be decompiling the APK using a tool like `apktool` may be of more help as it preserves the resources structure so you can see what language the different values belong to and thus delete languages you want to ignore. To speed upd ecompilation you can skip sources and only decompile resources: `apktool d -s apkfile.apk`.